# nvarchar extract part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have a varchar holding the duration of an event in 'HHHH:MM:SS'
So I was hoping to filter by the hours, so what I would like to do is get only the HHHH,
I was thinking of doing a substring(duration, 1, 4) but I'm not sure how to get it to stop at the colon, as we can get less than the four hours, such as '7:07:47' or '29:30:01'. Anything helps thanks guys!

Comment: but it's not really, as we can have '1234:13:13' it's a duration, so there is no conversion to date time.. or am I looking at it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `TIME` datatype instead. But anyway, here's the code you want:

```
DECLARE @YourTime VARCHAR(10)
SET @YourTime = '29:30:01'

SELECT LEFT(@YourTime,CHARINDEX(':',@YourTime,0)-1)
```